# Múltiplos Upload de imagens

Tags: php, jquery

Quero realizar múltiplos uploads porém aparece a seguinte mensagem:

> Notice: Undefined index: files in C:\xampp\htdocs\fotolog\adm\upload_fotos.php on line 6
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\fotolog\adm\upload_fotos.php on line 6

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#uploadForm').on('submit',function(e)){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url:"upload_fotos.php"
            data: new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            processData: function(data)
            success: function(data){
                $("#galley").html(data);
                alert("imagem foi");

            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="container">  
    <form id="uploadForm" action="upload_fotos.php" method="post">  
        <div id="gallery"></div><div style="clear:both;"></div><br /><br />  
        <div class="col-md-4" align="right">  
            <label>Upload Multiple Image</label>  
        </div>  
        <div class="col-md-4">  
            <input name="files[]" type="file" multiple />  
        </div>  
        <div class="col-md-4">  
            <input type="submit" submitvalue="Submit" />  
        </div>  
        <div style="clear:both"></div>  
    </form>  
</div>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
 <?php  
 //upload.php  
 $output = '';  
 if(is_array($_FILES))   
 {  
      foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $name => $value)  
      {  
        $file_name = explode(".", $_FILES['files']['name'][$name]);  
        $allowed_extension = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif"); 
           if(in_array($file_name[1], $allowed_ext))  
           {  
                $new_name = md5(rand()) . '.' . $file_name[1];  
                $sourcePath = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$name];  
                $targetPath = "foto/".$new_name;  
                if(move_uploaded_file($sourcePath, $targetPath))  
                {  
                     $output .= '<img src="'.$targetPath.'" width="150px" height="180px" />';  
                }                 
           }            
      }  
      echo $output;  
 }  
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

É tanta coisa errada no seu código que eu nem sei como você chegou a obter o erro, na verdade eu acho que devido a esta série de erros ao invés de Ajax o formulário estava sendo enviado por requisição normal, já que tinha erros de digitação no JS ele nem processava. Veja os problemas:

1. Parece que você não entende bem o que é Json (objeto)

   ```javascript
   $.ajax({                          <--- Falta definir o type: POST
       url:"upload_fotos.php"        <--- Falta virgula
       data: new FormData(this),
       contentType: false,
       processData: function(data)   <--- Função não terminada, na verdade isto deveria ser false e não uma função
       success: function(data){
           $("#galley").html(data);
           alert("imagem foi");

       }                             <--- Falta definir o error:function(), é fundamental
   });
   ```
2. Você trocou o nome das variáveis:

   ```javascript
   $allowed_extension = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif"); 

   if(in_array($file_name[1], $allowed_ext))
   ```

   Em um lugar você usa `$allowed_extension` e no outro `$allowed_ext`.

Seus problemas são uma série de falhas suas próprias com *erros de digitação*, e provavelmente você não se atentou a ler a documentação do jQuery, vou lhe dar uma dica <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> e <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> em códigos até funciona, mas não vai adiantar muito se você não souber o minimo do que você esta fazendo.

### Código corrigido

jQuery (**recomendo** que leia a documentação http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

```javascript
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#uploadForm').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", //O type que faltava
            url: "upload_fotos.php",
            processData: false, //Aqui tem que ser false para pode enviar FormData
            contentType: false,
            data: new FormData(this),
            success: function(data){
                $("#galley").html(data);
                alert("imagem foi");
            },
            error: function(a, b, c) { //Isto ser para tratar erros de HTTP ou conexão
                alert([a, b, c]);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

O PHP pode ficar assim:

```php
if(is_array($_FILES))
{
    $output = '';

    foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $name => $value)
    {
        $file_name = explode(".", $_FILES['files']['name'][$name]);
        $allowed_extension = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif");

        if(in_array($file_name[1], $allowed_extension))
        {
            $new_name = md5(rand()) . '.' . $file_name[1];
            $sourcePath = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$name];
            $targetPath = "foto/".$new_name;

            if(move_uploaded_file($sourcePath, $targetPath))
            {
                $output .= '<img src="'.$targetPath.'" width="150px" height="180px" />';
            }
        }
    }
    echo $output;
}
```